# Android - Force app to stay "working" while background or closed

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I've wrote an app that send gps locations every 2 minutes. The app is working fine but needs to be running and can't be on background or closed.

Is possible to switch this behavior and keep sending the gps location if the app is running on background or closed?

I've read about BroadcastReceivers but I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use Service / Background Service

Comment: I'm gonna check the docs. Ty

Comment: See this:- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

Answer (score 3):

> Is possible to switch this behavior and keep sending the gps location if the app is running on background or closed?

Definitely not on Android 8.0+, as you will not get fresh GPS fixes very often when the device is asleep.

It is also impossible in general, as the user can stop your app whenever the user wants to, and Android can terminate your process whenever it feels that this is necessary. Plus, on Android 6.0+, Doze mode and app standby will prevent your app from doing work very often when the device is asleep.

A foreground service on the battery optimization whitelist and a continuous partial wakelock is the closest that you will get to being able to get to doing what you want. This will drain the battery very quickly, which will tend to make users rather angry.

Comment: It's a phone from our company and we would like to control what user is doing while driving. I could make a bigger interval but we really need to control if user is using facebook while he is driving. Do you have any idea how to reach it? For now, I'm using GPS data to calc an average speed.

Comment: @placplacboom: If the user is using Facebook while driving, the user will soon be dead from an accident, at which point your problem changes to one that has little to do with Android app development. Beyond that, I have no idea what "it" is in "Do you have any idea how to reach it?". If "it" is "prevent the user from using Facebook while driving", I think that through the device owner APIs you can control whether apps can be installed and so forth. So, focus on not allowing Facebook on the device.